# Pyramid cookbook WSGI example out of date?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, pyramid

Working through this example in the Pyramid cookbook:  http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html

This stanza is throwing an error: (when adapted to my circumstances anturally)

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = '/Users/chrism/modwsgi/env/myapp/production.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

The error message:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=27548): Target WSGI script '/home/rsadmin/modwsgi/env/hydra/hydra.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=27548): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/rsadmin/modwsgi/env/hydra/hydra.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/rsadmin/modwsgi/env/hydra/hydra.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
     from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ImportError: No module named pyramid.paster
```

I suspect what has happened is that `pyramid.paster` has been refactored since this doc was written, and no one has had time to correct it for the newest release.

Can anyone tell me what ought to be there instead, nowadays ?

TIA,
Erik

Comment: I'm wrong about the cause. pyramid.paster is still there and not the source of the problem.  Somehow though the python-path setting in my vhosts file isn't being followed. I think...

Comment: Yep, something is wrong with your python-path. The example in the documentation does actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the hydra.wsgi script in the wrong directory. It needed to be one up from the path it was in: should be here:

```
/home/rsadmin/modwsgi/env/hydra.wsgi
```

The example in the cookbook is correct.